# Rolify gem is not working with Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.2.13. Before adding rolify into my gemfile the app is working fine. After adding the gem in gem file and run the bundle command, my app is not working it raises the following issue:

```
   ruby-1.9.2-p320@roles/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:13:in `[]':    can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)


   from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@roles/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
   from script/rails:6:in `require'
   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem with rolify 3.3.0 version gem. If anyone want to use rolify, use below 3.3.0 version presently 3.2.0 is available otherwise it brakes your bones. :)